# WebService Error: 404 Not found - No context found for request

Tags: java, web-services

I used the code below to publish ssl webservice. when I browse `https://localhost/` it give me this Error:

```
404 Not Found

No context found for request
```

the code:

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new TicketQueryImpl());
        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext ssl = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
                .getInstance(javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        store.load(new FileInputStream("c:/thekey.txt"), "password".toCharArray());
        keyFactory.init(store, "password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustFactory.init(store);
        ssl.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(ssl);
        HttpsServer httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 443), 443);
        httpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);
        HttpContext httpContext = httpsServer.createContext("/127.0.0.1:443/");
        httpsServer.start();

        endpoint.publish(httpContext);
```

how can I solve this problem, and why this problem occures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How Stupid I am. the URI in `https.createContext(uri)` is not URI of whole path. I changed

```
HttpContext httpContext = httpsServer.createContext("/127.0.0.1:443/");
```

to

```
HttpContext httpContext = httpsServer.createContext("/test");
```

and then browsed `https://127.0.0.1/test?wsdl`
It worked.